# I think my syntax is incorrect for writing/reading from Firebase, but I'm unsure where to start

Tags: android, firebase

I am attempting to make a simple app for personal and maybe a few coworkers to use. I am having trouble successfully reading and writing into a Firebase Database.

Some of this code is ripped so there may be mistakes I am looking over without realizing.

I am fairly positive this is something silly and stupid easy to fix, but I just can't see it and have had no success with searching.

The way I am thinking of putting the information into the database is in this fashion.

[possible layout?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJetU.png)

If there is a better way to lay this out, I'm all ears lol. Hope someone can point me in the right direction. All the files have the proper top lines or 2, and sometimes missing the bottom brace. My computer is being super derpy and deleting some lines for some reason when I am trying to copy/paste.

Rundown of what I am trying to accomplish.

- App that will show/store NSNs, name, and description of items
- User can enter all of this information themselves to be entered into the database or can search a database for the information. Search part is coming next after I get the easier part down.
- information is presented in a CardView form, eventually to be made clickable for more information. information on card will be NSN, name, description, and eventually a picture.
- All information is either from user input or directly into the database.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.OnProgressListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import com.milapps.jd.militemnsnfinder.ShowItemInfo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Button Variables

private Button btnChoose, btnUpload, btnSubmit, btnReturn;

private final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 71;
private Uri filePath;

//Firebase storage
FirebaseStorage storage;
StorageReference storageReference;



// Declaring String variable ( In which we are storing firebase server URL 
).
public static final String Firebase_Server_URL = "https://mil-item-nsn-
finder.firebaseio.com/";

// Declaring String variables to store name & phone number get from   .
String nsnHolder, nameHolder, descHolder;

//Declaring firebase database
Firebase firebase;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;

// Root Database Name for Firebase Database.
public static final String Database_Path = "Military NSN Database";

//Declaring EditTexts
EditText NameEditText, NSNEditText, DescEditText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit_iv);
    btnReturn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnReturn_iv);
    btnChoose = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnChoose_iv);
    btnUpload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnUpload_iv);

    NameEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.itemNameIV);
    NSNEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.itemNSN_iv);
    DescEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.itemDesc_iv);


    Firebase.setAndroidContext(MainActivity.this);

    firebase = new Firebase(Firebase_Server_URL);

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Database_Path);




    //Firebase init
    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    storageReference = storage.getReference();


    btnChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            chooseImage();
        }

    });

    btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            uploadImage();
        }

    });

    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            ItemInfo itemInfo = new ItemInfo();

            GetDataFromEditText();

            // Adding item name into class function object.
            itemInfo.setItemName(nameHolder);

            // Adding item NSN into class function object.
            itemInfo.setItemNSN(nsnHolder);

            //Adding item desc into class function object
            itemInfo.setItemDesc(descHolder);

            // Getting the ID from firebase database.
            String ItemIDFromServer = databaseReference.push().getKey();

            // Adding the both name and number values using student details 
             class object using ID.
            databaseReference.child(ItemIDFromServer).setValue(itemInfo);

            // Showing Toast message after successfully data submit.
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Successfully Added", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });


    btnReturn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
 ShowItemInfo.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}
    private void uploadImage(){
        if(filePath != null){
            final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
            progressDialog.show();

            StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("images/"+ 
UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            ref.putFile(filePath)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new 
OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot 
taskSnapshot) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uploaded", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed" 
+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(new 
OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>(){
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot 
taskSnapshot){
                            double progress = (100.0 
*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                            progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + 
(int)progress+"%");
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    private void chooseImage(){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select 
Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && data!= null && data.getData() != null)
        {
            filePath = data.getData();
            try{
                Bitmap bitmap = 
MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);

            }
            catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
public void GetDataFromEditText(){

    nameHolder = NameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    descHolder = DescEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    nsnHolder = NSNEditText.getText().toString().trim();

}


ItemInfo.java

    package com.milapps.jd.militemnsnfinder;


public class ItemInfo {

    private String itemName;
    private String itemNSN;
    private String itemDesc;

    public ItemInfo() {

    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    public String getItemNSN() {
        return itemNSN;
    }

    public void setItemNSN(String itemNSN) {
        this.itemNSN = itemNSN;
    }

    public String getItemDesc() {
        return itemDesc;
    }

    public void setItemDesc(String itemDesc) {
        this.itemDesc = itemDesc;
    }

}
RecyclerViewAdapter.java


import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    List<ItemInfo> MainImageUploadInfoList;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<ItemInfo> TempList) {

        this.MainImageUploadInfoList = TempList;

        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view =
```

LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
   R.layout.recyclerview_items, parent, false);

```
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ItemInfo itemInfo = MainImageUploadInfoList.get(position);

        holder.itemName_iv.setText(itemInfo.getItemName());

        holder.itemNSN_iv.setText(itemInfo.getItemNSN());

        holder.itemDesc_iv.setText(itemInfo.getItemDesc());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return MainImageUploadInfoList.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView itemName_iv;
        public TextView itemNSN_iv;
        public TextView itemDesc_iv;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);

            itemName_iv = (TextView) 
itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemName_iv);
            itemDesc_iv = (TextView) 
itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemDesc_iv);
            itemNSN_iv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemNSN_iv);
        }
    }
}
```

ShowItemInfo.java

```
package com.milapps.jd.militemnsnfinder;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ShowItemInfo extends AppCompatActivity {


    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    List<ItemInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.show_items_list);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new 
LinearLayoutManager(ShowItemInfo.this));

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ShowItemInfo.this);

        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Data from Firebase Database");

        progressDialog.show();

        databaseReference = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(MainActivity.Database_Path);

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                    ItemInfo itemInfo = 
dataSnapshot.getValue(ItemInfo.class);

                    list.add(itemInfo);
                }

                adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(ShowItemInfo.this, list);

                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                progressDialog.dismiss();

            }
        });

    }
}


activity_main.xml

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.milapps.jd.militemnsnfinder.MainActivity"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter New Item"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/itemNameIV"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Enter Item Name(Stock)" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/itemNSN_iv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/itemNameIV"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Enter Item NSN" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/itemDesc_iv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/itemNSN_iv"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Enter Item Description" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnChoose_iv"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnUpload_iv"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnUpload_iv"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="Choose" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnUpload_iv"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/itemDesc_iv"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnChoose_iv"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnChoose_iv"
        android:text="Upload" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit_iv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnChoose_iv"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Submit" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnReturn_iv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnSubmit_iv"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="Return" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnChoose_iv"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Upload Picture(Optional)" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

content_show_student_details.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.milapps.jd.militemnsnfinder.ShowItemInfo"
    tools:showIn="@layout/show_items_list">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


recyclerview_items.xml

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemName_iv"
            android:layout_width="233dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:text="something" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemNSN_iv"
            android:layout_width="233dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="something" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemDesc_iv"
            android:layout_width="232dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/itemName_iv"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/itemName_iv"
            android:text="something" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            card_view:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

show_items_list.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.milapps.jd.militemnsnfinder.ShowItemInfo">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">


    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, in your POJO make sure the name of the constants are equal to the ones in your firebase database, first in your firebase database you have item Name and in your pojo `itemName`  , you should put in your firebase either `item_Name` or `itemName` , if you put `item_Name` refactor the name in your pojo but keep the same names in the pojo and the firebase

Second, your reference must be like this `.child("items").child("item_NSN")....` , or `.child("items/item_NSN")`..... but please do not use blank spaces in names inside firebase

Last, please update your firebase rules if they are not able to write and read for everyone without sign in first

go to your realtime database and find rules, inside you should have this

```
// These rules require authentication
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

if you want to each one read and write data without authentication just change that rules to this

```
 // These rules do not require authentication
// These rules give anyone, even people who are not users of your app,
// read and write access to your database
    {
      "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
      }
    }
```

Comment: Just woke up thanks for the answer! I posted something else below with where I have gone next. Still does not work correctly and I have changed the layout of the database to have no spaces and to match the POJO.

Answer (score 0):

So my brain is no longer fried. So when trying to enter information via the submit button, I "think" I fixed my reference but I'm not 100%. Still a little confused from it.

```
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String itemNSN;

            ItemInfo itemInfo = new ItemInfo();

            GetDataFromEditText();

            // Adding item name into class function object.
            itemInfo.setItemName(nameHolder);

            // Adding item NSN into class function object.
            itemInfo.setItemNSN(nsnHolder);
            itemNSN = nsnHolder;

            //Adding item desc into class function object
            itemInfo.setItemDesc(descHolder);

            // Getting the ID from firebase database.
            String ItemIDFromServer = databaseReference.push().getKey();

            // Adding the both name and number values using student details 
class object using ID.
            databaseReference.child("items").setValue(itemNSN);
            databaseReference.child("items/itemNSN").setValue(itemInfo);


            // Showing Toast message after successfully data submit.
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Successfully Added",  
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

Then to pull all the information via the return button, I am unsure of what is supposed to be but I haven't changed it at all. I have the cardview layout I would like for it. but this is my btnReturn clickListener.

```
    btnReturn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
ShowItemInfo.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```